# Problem placing banner at bottom of layout

Tags: java, android, mobile

For my app, I hide the titlebar and notification bar for my activity using the themes feature in the manifest file. At the bottom of the activity, I want there to be a 48dip high ad banner and above this the rest of the space should be filled with a object from my class GameView, where this just extends SurfaceView the way seen in the Lunar Lander sample.

My current layout does this task for me:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <GameView android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="48dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, there is a problem when I switch away from my app with the home key (which cases the notification bar to return) and then switch back to my activity. When I switch back, the screen goes black for a short time, my drawn surface view appears below the notification bar, the notification bar then animates up and disappears, my surface view then shifts to the top of the screen. The problem is that a black horizontal rectangle is now masking the top of my ad banner, where this bar looks the same height as the notification bar. Ascii art:

```
-------------
|           |
|           |   <- surface view the same size as expected
|           |
|           |
#############   <- black rectangle
|           |   <- ad banner with the top part masked by the rectangle
-------------
```

It's as if the views are laid out before the notification bar disappears and when the bar disappears the views are laid out again but something goes wrong laying out the ad bar.

Any tips on how I can fix this?

I'm on Android 2.1 if it helps. I tried an alternative RelativeLayout approach but had the same issue. Another alternative might fix it perhaps but I can't think of anything.

Edit: Relevant manifest code for setting up my activity:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
....
```

Comment: Please post a bit of the code from your `Activity` that shows which methods are setting the `NO_TITLE` feature and `FULLSCREEN` flags and in what order.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my manifest code that sets the app to fullscreen. I don't do this using method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may go away if you use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in your manifest rather than removing the notification bar via Java code. Leastways, I do not see the animation effect you are describing when I test with [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) that uses this theme.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already switching to fullscreen this way. There are no method calls doing this. I think this issue is specifically to do with having a fixed size banner under my surface view (your project only seems to use one big surface view in the layout). Can you think of any things I can try? I'm out of options right now. I've noticed that if I replace my surface view with e.g. an image view I don't get the same problem. I'm thinking it might have something to do with when the surface view is deciding what size it wants to be.

Comment: @rebeccamaher: There's no question that `SurfaceView` is a strange bird. On what device are you seeing this behavior? You might also try switching to a `RelativeLayout`, so the position of the banner is determined by explicit layout rules, rather than by how large the `SurfaceView` winds up being.

Comment: @rebeccamaher: I'm testing this on a Milestone but it happens in the emulator too. I've tried a relative layout approach. I suppose I can try different permutations of which view is relative to what.